# What data will be removed when I clear data in the Android setting?

Tags: android, setting

Are there anyone know what exactly data will be removed when I clear the setting data in the setting? Currently, I find a bug in WallPaperManager. After I clear the setting data, my pad cannot change to other wall papers. I track some piece of code and I figure out there may be some observer/listener are removed. So, I would want to know what kind of will be removed!

Answer (score 1):

Data in internal storage 
Your `Database,SharedPreference....` removed but not external storage(in sdcard) data removed...see  this   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref